# How to stop list at certain point with indexing?

Tags: python, indexing

I would like to show only a list of integers before the value '---' does not matter where in list it is i would like it to stop at that ('---') point.

Input:

```
list1 = ['pop', 'sop', 'kla', 'so', 'Lu', 'ys', 'Se', '---', 'rop', 'pol']
```

What i want as output:

```
list1 ['pop', 'sop', 'kla', 'so', 'Lu', 'ys', 'Se']
```

I have tried indexing but I am stuck atm

Comment: Have you tried `.index()` or `.find()` and the use the output of that to do the index?

Comment: I used the wrong methods, thank you for help, i got the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can slice your list up to that item with this:

```
list1[:list1.index('---')]
```

It will stop at the index position of `'---'`

Comment: It does not stop there it only removes index '---' , just tried it

Comment: Yes it does. It doesn't remove anything from the list, it slices the list from the start up until the index position of the '---' entry. (So long as it exists in the list of course.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use slicing on the output of `index()` as:

```
list2 = list1[:list1.index('---')] # ['pop', 'sop', 'kla', 'so', 'Lu', 'ys', 'Se']
```

As @deceze pointed, it throws an error if the element doesn't exist in the list in which case you could add a check in the slicing part as:

```
list2 = list1[:list1.index('---') if '---' in list1 else len(list1)]
```

Comment: Note that this raises a `ValueError` should `---` not exist in the list…

Comment: With that fixed version, you're now iterating (at least part of) the list *thrice*…!

Comment: I thought we don't need to iterate over the list to get the `len()`, do we need to?

Comment: No, not for that, but: once for the `in` check, then again for the `index`, and then again for the slicing (though that is probably pretty efficient).

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import takewhile

list1 = list(takewhile(lambda s: s != '---', list1))
```

See [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile).

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you want:

```
list1 = ['pop', 'sop', 'kla', 'so', 'Lu', 'ys', 'Se', '---', 'rop', 'pol']
x=list1[0]
i=0;
while x!='---':
    x=list1[i]
    i=i+1
    if x!='---':
        print(x,end=', ')
```